# Understanding the precise definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, solution-verification

I'm attempting to understand the exact definition of a limit, but I'm struggling to do so.

For instance, why is it incorrect to say that the limit of x as it approaches 2 is equal to 10? $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}x=10$

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,0<|x-c|<\delta\longrightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
I choose $\delta=100$. So why the following statement is not correct?

$$0<|x-2|<100\longrightarrow|x-10|<\epsilon,\quad\forall \epsilon>0$$

Comment: Take $\epsilon=1$ and $x=100$. You do have $|x-2| < 100$, but you don't have $|x-10| < \epsilon$.

Comment: So from the first part we get $2<x<102$ and from the second part we get $9<x<11$ and it is subset of the first part. So why is it wrong?

Comment: You forgot the "for every x such that ..."See [Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable)

Comment: First of all, you almost always want to choose $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon.$ One $\delta$ will not work for all $\epsilon$ as $x\to a$ unless your function is constant in $(a-\delta,a+\delta).$

Comment: The first part says $2-100<x<2+100,$ not $2<x<100,$ @Ariana

Comment: First part says it must be greater than zero @Thomas Andrews.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA you are right. I missed "for every x" part

Comment: "...and it is the subset of the first part." That's the problem, the definition says that the first part is supposed to be a subset of the second part. The definition has $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$, so if ANY $x$ satisfies $0<|x-a|<\delta$, it has to satisfy $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @TimLam: That is not true. $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $\varepsilon$, but not on $x$. This is because the $\exists \delta>0$ occurs after $\forall \varepsilon>0$ in the definition of the limit, but *before* the $\forall x$ part.

Comment: @Ariana That only means $x\neq 2.$ $x$ can still be $-10.$

Comment: @Joe : yes, it is my mistakes. I suddenly mixed with the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implicitly asking two questions:

> Why is not the case that $\lim_{x\to 2}x=10$?

> Why is not true that for every $\varepsilon>0$,
> $$
> 0<|x-2|<100\implies |x-10|<\varepsilon \, ?
> $$

Let me address the second question first. Notice that in the statement
$$
\forall\epsilon>0:0<|x-2|<100\implies |x-10|<\varepsilon
$$
the symbol $x$ is not quantified; that is, we aren't explicitly told whether to read the sub-formula $0<|x-2|<100\implies |x-10|<\varepsilon$ as being true for all values of $x$ or just true for *some* value of $x$. However, in such a situation, it is common mathematical convention to assume the first interpretation. So the statement to which you refer is actually an abbreviation of
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0:\forall x:0<|x-2|<100\implies |x-10|<\varepsilon \, .
$$
Now you ask why this is false: well, it's because we can find values of $\varepsilon>0$ and $x$ such that $0<|x-2|<100$ does not imply $|x-10|<\varepsilon$. For instance, if $\varepsilon=1$ and $x=50$ then $0<|x-2|<100$, but it is not the case that $|x-10|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, the implication $0<|x-2|<100\implies |x-10|<\varepsilon$ does not hold for all values of $\varepsilon>0$ and $x$.

Now let's look at your first question. In general, to say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq l$ means
$$
\exists \varepsilon>0:\forall \delta>0:\exists x:(0<|x-a|<\delta)\land \bigl(|f(x)-l|\ge \varepsilon\bigr) \, .
$$
Here, $a=2$, $f(x)=x$, and $l=10$, so we are trying to prove that
$$
\exists\varepsilon>0:\forall \delta>0:\exists x:(0<|x-2|<\delta)\land \bigl(|x-10|\ge \varepsilon\bigr) \, .
$$
This is a good exercise. Hint: $\varepsilon=1$ suffices to prove the statement. So try showing that
$$
\forall \delta >0:\exists x:(0<|x-2|<\delta)\land \bigl(|x-10|\ge 1\bigr)
$$
Earlier, we found that if $\delta=100$, then there is a corresponding $x$, namely $50$, such that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ and $|x-10|\ge 1$. But you need to prove that for an *arbitrary* $\delta>0$, there is an $x$ (dependent on $\delta$) such that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ and $|x-10|\ge 1$.

An alternative method of showing that $\lim_{x\to 2}x\neq 10$ is to use the uniqueness of limits: this is the theorem which states that if $f(x)\to l$ as $x\to a$, but also $f(x)\to l'$ as $x \to a$, then $l=l'$. Indeed, it is because of this theorem that the notation $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ makes sense to begin with. Since $x\to2$ as $x\to2$ (prove this!), it cannot be the case that $x\to10$ as $x\to2$.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers and comments here are trying to clear up your misunderstanding. I am responding to this particular question:

> So why the following statement is not correct?

$$0<|x-2|<100\longrightarrow|x-10|<\epsilon,\quad\forall \epsilon>0$$

Since that statement says "$\forall \epsilon>0$" it should be true for any particular $\epsilon$. So let's consider $\epsilon = 5$.  The left side of the implication (the hypothesis) is $0<|x-2|<100$. That's surely true for $x=101$. But the right side is then |101-10|<5, which is false.